# Ошибка PHP. syntax error

Tags: php

Выдаёт ошибку `syntax error, unexpected '$login' (T_VARIABLE) in W:\domains\login\register.php on line 7`. В чём ошибка не могу понять?

```
<?php
  $link = mysqli_connect('ip', 'root', 'root', 'launcher');
  $login = $_POST["login"];
  $pass = $_POST["pass"];
  if(!empty($login) && !empty($pass)){
    $pass_md5 = md5($pass);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO auth VALUES ('$login', '$pass_md5')';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    echo 'Вы успешно зарегистрировались!';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно будет так:

```
"INSERT INTO auth VALUES ('$login', '$pass_md5')";
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136665/discussion-on-answer-by----php-syntax-error).